# How can I have git not treat these as subproject

Tags: git, composer-php

I'm using PHP/Composer and am required to commit dependencies - I had [read on the composer site](http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md) you can prevent the issues around sub projects by adding the following to .gitignore:

```
vendor/.git
```

However, its still treating the folders within `vendor/` as subprojects when I attempt to stage & commit.

Is there a way to correct this problem? None of the folders within `vendor/` have been previously committed. I'd like to do this without manually deleting the .git folders within `vendor`.

Comment: It works IF you actually delete these .git folders. And it probably does not work because there is no `vendor/.git` folder to be ignored, but plenty of `vendor/xxx/yyy/.git` folders.

Comment: And you should try to `--prefer-dist`. If you can avoid cloning entire Git repos, things will be faster as well.

Comment: @Sven in git folder/filename will ignore every occourance of that file within that folder or its subfolders. also, speed is not an issue and the constraint is work related, most of the packages do not have tags

Comment: I do think the correct .gitignore pattern would be `vendor/**/.git` here, with `**` being zero or any number of directories. This pattern does exist, and I'd think it counterintuitive for a pattern without wildcards to behave like having wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never should add content of vendor into your vcs, it will make bad things happen.
Also there is absolute no use case, besides low quality workflows, which make this necessary.

And if you still want to do it, use the --prefer-dist, and make sure, no package is installed via VCS.

But still, If you need to do this, your workflow is wrong and broken.